# unexpected ':' AND unexpected ')' errors

Tags: ruby

I'm running the following code in ruby version 1.8.7

```
require 'csv'

FILENAME = 'filename'

cleansed_output = File.open('filename_cleaned.csv','wb')

CSV.open(FILENAME, encoding: 'ISO8859-1') do |output|
  row_number = 1
  loop do
    begin
      break unless row = output.shift
      cleansed_output << row.to_csv
    rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => e
      puts "Malformed row #: #{row_number}"
    ensure
      puts "Row number: #{row_number}" if row_number % 10000 == 0
      row_number += 1
    end
  end
end

cleansed_output.close
```

and I'm getting the following errors:

```
csv_cleanser2.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
CSV.open(FILENAME, encoding: 'ISO8859-1') do |output|
                            ^
csv_cleanser2.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
CSV.open(FILENAME, encoding: 'ISO8859-1') do |output|
```

I'm trying to clean a csv with a broken delimiter. Anyone know what the problem is here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're using ruby 1.8.7, but you're trying to use the 1.9 hash syntax:

```
CSV.open(FILENAME, encoding: 'ISO8859-1') do |output|
```

try using the old school hash rockets:

```
CSV.open(FILENAME, :encoding => 'ISO8859-1') do |output|
```

Comment: Ah, there we go. That fixed the first part, but now I'm getting another strange error:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:89:in `open': 'mode' must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb' (ArgumentError)
 from csv_cleanser2.rb:7

I'm using 'wb', so why would this give me an error? Another version problem?